# Can someone help me understand this simple derivation for hall voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a question regarding the derivation for hall voltage as shown in this image:
[image]

How did they get $\Delta V_H = E_H d$ term? ($d$  is the width of the conductor)

Answer (score 4):

$\Delta V=\phi_2-\phi_1$ where $\phi$ are electrostatic potentials at the given points. By definition, electrostatic potential is a line integral

$$\phi=-\int_C\!\vec E\cdot \mathrm d\vec s$$

along an arbitrary path (in this case, along the width of the conductor).

$$\vec E\cdot \mathrm d\vec s=E\ \mathrm ds$$

(both vectors have the same direction) and therefore (as E is constant along the width)

$$\Delta V=\phi_2-\phi_1=-\int_0^2\!E\ \mathrm ds -\left(-\int_0^1\!E\ \mathrm ds\right)=\int_2^0\!E\ \mathrm ds +\int_0^1\!E\ \mathrm ds=\int_2^1\!E\ \mathrm ds=E\int_2^1\!\mathrm ds=ED$$

Hope it is clear now. :)

Comment: Your answer would benefit from equation formatting using MathJax (= LateX). See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Answer (score -1):

The magnitude of the electromagnetic force is equal to the voltage difference. It is also the closed loop integral of the electric field times the distance it's over. In this case these two are in the same direction, and thus equal to $Ed$.

Comment: I don't think the electromagnetic force is equal to the voltage difference! They don't even have similar units.

Comment: 'is equal to' is wrong; unless you mean emf? Which is 'electromotive force'.